# What is best practice in Gitlab CI/CD for setup of a Python virtual environment

Tags: python, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

### Problem

Right now I am writing a `.gitlab-ci.yml` for a Python project hosted on Gitlab.

I do not really know where to put the setup of a virtual environment and the installation of requirements from the `requirements.txt`.

My primary resource is the [Gitlab `Python.gitlab-ci.yml` template](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Python.gitlab-ci.yml).

In there, virtualenv is installed before every job, using the `before_script` keyword and a virtualenv named 'venv' is created:

```
before_script:
  - python -V  # Print out python version for debugging
  - pip install virtualenv
  - virtualenv venv
  - source venv/bin/activate
```

Additionally, caching for 'venv' gets set up:

```
cache:
  paths:
    - .cache/pip
    - venv/
```

I want to do the same in my script and additionally install from the `requirements.txt` in my repo. Afterwards, I want to execute code analysis (pylint, flake8) and tests in different stages. If I append `pip install -r requirements.txt` to `before_script`, it gets executed with every job, which produces unnecessary logs.

### Question

Wouldn't it make more sense to

1. Define cached sub-directories. (as seen above)
2. Only call `source venv/bin/activate` in `before_script`.
3. Add a stage or job for setup that calls `virtualenv venv` to generate an environment *once*. This job also calls `pip install -r requirements.txt` *once*.

Where would you create your venv and install your requirements?

Comment: If the python package is running within a docker container, a virtualenv can be bypassed, by treating the container as the virtual environment.

Answer (score 5):

For some python projects hosted in Gitlab the process I follow is:

1. Create a Dockerfile. And here is where the `pip install -r requirements` is executed while creating the docker image that the different Runners will use in every different stage
2. Pulling the Docker image created in step 1 in every other further stage of the pipeline ensures that you only run once the `pip install -r requirements.txt` probably in a stage you might call `build`

Example:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM rasa/rasa-sdk:latest
MAINTAINER William Galindez Arias
COPY ./actions /app/actions/
COPY  ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
WORKDIR /app
USER root
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
USER 1001
ENTRYPOINT [""] 
CMD python -m rasa_sdk --actions actions -vv
```

The first step of the following .gitlab-ci.yml file builds the Docker image using the docker file above, and then pushes it for other stages

```
stages:
   - build 
   - test

build-image:
 stage: build
 script:
   - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
   - docker build -t $ACTIONS_CONTAINER_IMAGE -f Dockerfile .
   - docker push $ACTIONS_CONTAINER_IMAGE
 tags:
    - docker

test-action:
   stage: test
   image: $ACTIONS_CONTAINER_IMAGE
   script:
       - echo "testing  sdk "
```